# jQuery - Subtract the unit price depending on quanitity

Tags: jquery, subtraction

**What I'm trying to achieve:**
I want to subtract 0.09 from:
`<span class="item_price cd_price">0.53</span>`
When the input of:
 `<input type="text" value="50" class="item_Quantity cd_quantity">`
Is above 100.

**What I have tried:**

```
$('.cd_quantity').blur(function(){
       if ( $(this).val() >= 50 && $(this).val() <= 99 ) {
         $('.cd_price').text('0.53')
       }
       if ( $(this).val() >= 100 && $(this).val() <= 199 ) {
         $('.cd_price').text('0.44')
       }
    })
```

Although all this does is replace the contents of the span. And I'm not too clued up on sums with query.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Is the sum only for the current CD or for the total sum of all CD's?

Comment: For the current CD, as the total is calculated from the current price.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a way to safely get the item price after the quantity if the quantity is changed back to under 100.

Have your markup like this:

```
<span class="item_price cd_price" data-item_price="0.53"></span>

<input type="text" value="50" class="item_Quantity cd_quantity">
```

and your javascript:

```
$(".cd_quantity").on("keyup", function() {
    var item_price = $(".cd_price").data("item_price");
    var discount = 0;

    if (this.value > 100) discount = 0.09;
    $(".cd_price").text((item_price - discount).toFixed(2));
}).trigger("keyup");​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/MpBXY/

Comment: Perfect. I wouldn't have even thought of that!

Answer (score 1):

Following your task, it can be done as follows:

```
$(".cd_quantity").on("blur", function() {
    if (this.value > 100) {
        $(".cd_price").text(function(i, val) {
            return (val - 0.09).toFixed(2);
        });
    }
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/GSTcR/